# rails first_or_create for multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I was wondering, is it possible to do find or create multiple objects at once in `Ruby on Rails` ?

Do something like as follows (i know that it's not  valid code for RoR but just wondering is it possible to do something like this ?)

```
class User 
end  

hash = [] 
hash << { name: 'Bob'}
hash << { name: 'Jim'}  

User.where(hash).first_or_create!
```

The meaning of this is to `minimise number of queries` needed to do something like this

```
 hash.map {|u| User.where(u).first_or_create!}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `hash.map { ... }` ?

Comment: Too many queries to DB.

Comment: @Зелёный: Because `map` would result in multiple queries and the OP is trying to *minimise number of queries*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try this:

Add import gem to your gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-import', '~> 0.10.0'
```

Then in your controller:

```
create_user = [] 

create_user << {name: "Bob"}
create_user << {name: "jim"}

User.import create_user
```

This will insert just with a single query in your database.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible in Ruby. Please check the following code,

```
hash = [] 
hash << { name: 'Bob' }
hash << { name: 'Jim' }

User.create(hash)
```

Two users will be created based on the data you have added in the hash. Also, the key of the dictionary should be based on the column names.

Comment: I'm talking about find or create, not a simple create!